# Finite morphisms between algebraic varieties are flat?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a finite (surjective) morphism between two algebraic varieties. I know when $X$ and $Y$ are non-singular and $\dim Y =1$, $f$ is flat. But in general, is it true that $f$ is a flat morphism?

Comment: See this question also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7559/finite-surjective-l-c-i-morphism-is-flat

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are both regular, then this is true. In fact, it's true more generally if $Y$ is regular and $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay (Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra, Corollary 18.17). In general it's certainly false.

Comment: This fact goes by the name of "miracle flatness" in Vakil's lecture notes.